# Does scoping behave differently for targets and variables?

Tags: cmake

I have a parent CMake file that contains,

```
if(USE_MYMATH)
  add_subdirectory(MathFunctions)
  list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS MathFunctions)

  message(STATUS "${MyString}")
endif()

# ...

target_link_libraries(compute_square_root PUBLIC 
  ${EXTRA_LIBS} tutorial_compiler_flags
)
```

Inside the CMakeLists.txt for MathFunctions contains,

```
add_library(MathFunctions mysqrt.cxx)

target_include_directories(MathFunctions
  INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

set(MyString "Some Text")
message(STATUS "${MyString}")
```

I am confused about the scoping. It seems here that `target_link_libraries` can correctly reference the target that was created by the child CMakeLists.txt when running `add_subdirectory(MathFunctions)` (In particular, `add_library(MathFunctions mysqrt.cxx)`), however, it cannot correctly access the variables that were also created in the same scope (`MyString`).

Are targets and variables scoped differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are scoped differently. Targets are visible at any scope after the point that they have been defined. Regular (non-cache) variables are [scoped to directories, functions, and `block()`s](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables), and are only visible to script code in the same directory function, and block scope (same function scope, and same directory level, or subdirectories added by `add_subdirectory`). To define a variable in the parent directory's scope, you must define it like `set(<variable> <value>... PARENT_SCOPE)`. See the documentation for [the `set()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) for more info.

If you want to "pass" the definition of a variable up several scopes, you must call `set(... PARENT_SCOPE)` multiple times to go up each scope level.